# The "and" word between the Names of Allah

Tags: quran, asma-ul-husna

In the Qur'an the names (attributes) of Allah come (if they come as a group) without an "and" between them. I once heard or read that there is one exception to this. Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: As is written this hardly seem as enough information to start from.

Comment: Yes, but the question is clear. And with so much information already noted, it is possible that the answer is noted somewhere.